# How can I test this C function

Tags: c, pointers

I got a weird question to do as an exercise :

> Write a function which take a pointer of a pointer of a pointer of a pointer of a pointer of a pointer of a pointer of a pointer of a pointer of an int as a parameter and assign a value to it.

I think the function I wrote is right (please correct if it's not) but how can I test it ?

```
void function(int *********anInt)
{
    *********anInt = 5;
}
```

I tried :

```
int main(void) {
    int *********nbr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    function(nbr);
    printf("%d", *********nbr);
}
```

But I get a segfault, I just learned about `malloc` and `pointers` so I don't fully understand it.

Comment: What the hell kind of assignment is this?

Comment: Seems pretty stupid right -.- But I still have to do it so any help would be appreciated ;P

Comment: Looks like your assignment is meant to emphasize how pointers work, albeit they re-re-re... emphasized too much! You're missing ampersands (address of) for dereferncing!

Comment: Woot Woot! I'm in 42 too

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course, you can test it, although it looks weird.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int *********anInt)
{
    *********anInt = 5;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int *p1 = &n;
    int **p2 = &p1;
    int ***p3 = &p2;
    int ****p4 = &p3;
    int *****p5 = &p4;
    int ******p6 = &p5;
    int *******p7 = &p6;
    int ********p8 = &p7;
    function(&p8);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
int main() {
    int *********nbr;

            nbr = malloc(sizeof(int********));
           *nbr = malloc(sizeof(int*******));
          **nbr = malloc(sizeof(int******));
         ***nbr = malloc(sizeof(int*****));
        ****nbr = malloc(sizeof(int****));
       *****nbr = malloc(sizeof(int***));
      ******nbr = malloc(sizeof(int**));
     *******nbr = malloc(sizeof(int*));
    ********nbr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    function(nbr);
    printf("%d", *********nbr);
}
```

Comment: @md5 Ye, I thought it would be compact. Removed it until I come up with a better way :)

Comment: `&&&&&&&&&nbr` - you can't take an address of an address because it's not lvalue

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a ridiculous main program to go with the assignment from hell!

```
int main(void)
{
    int         l0 = 0;
    int        *l1 = &l0;
    int       **l2 = &l1;
    int      ***l3 = &l2;
    int     ****l4 = &l3;
    int    *****l5 = &l4;
    int   ******l6 = &l5;
    int  *******l7 = &l6;
    int ********l8 = &l7;

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", l0, *l1, **l2, ***l3, ****l4, *****l5,
           ******l6, *******l7, ********l8);
    function(&l8);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", l0, *l1, **l2, ***l3, ****l4, *****l5,
           ******l6, *******l7, ********l8);
    return 0;
}
```

Untested: maybe I didn't count something right, but the general idea is about correct.  This is a torture test — for innocent C programmers and for compilers.

Comment: haha well ridiculous question deserves a ridiculous answer I guess ;P

Comment: I guess some of those `*` should be `&`s in those declarations.

Comment: Yes; the RHS of the initializers needed ampersands, not stars.

Answer (score 2):

An `int**` is a pointer that points to a pointer:

```
int myInt;
int* pInt = &myInt;
int** ppInt = &pInt;
```

An `int***` is a pointer that points to a pointer that points to a pointer:

```
int*** pppInt = &ppInt;
```

To test your function, you need to carry this on and on, the right number of times.

Answer (score 1):

See md5's solution, however it lacks explaination

**Explained:**

The reason your test program didn't work is because malloc returns a `void*` which is simply a memory address (a pointer). You assigned this to an `int*****...` which means when the program tries to dereference down to the actual int what it's doing is first taking the memory address of the int and dereferencing it (which is okay) but after this since your value (5) is now the value it then derefences that, which should come back with your segfault.

Think of the assignment as nested dereferences:

```
int ********p8 = *anInt; // p8 == 5
int *******p7 = *p8; // This breaks since dereferencing memory
                     // address 5 results in a segfault
```

What was done to avoid this was we actually nested the pointers that way when dereferencing for assignment we have memory addresses (pointers) to dereference to eventually get to the memory address which stores the value.